# Run windows service from winform

Tags: windows, service

How can i control (start, stop) windows service from my windows application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// ADD "using System.ServiceProcess;" after you add the 
// Reference to the System.ServiceProcess in the solution Explorer
using System.ServiceProcess;

ServiceController myService = new ServiceController();    
myService.ServiceName = "ImapiService";

string svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();

if (svcStatus == "Running")
{
    myService.Stop();
}
else if(svcStatus == "Stopped")
{
    myService.Start();
}
else
{
    myService.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "run"? If you want to control (start, stop and otherwise manipulate) services installed on your local (or remote) machine, [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) is the way to go.